# How does keyboard.is_pressed() work in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm trying to figure out when i press 'u' only 1 times, why is it pressing 'w' infinite times. Print functions don't work neither but if i delet the  keyboard.press('w') and keyboard.release('w'), the print functions start to work correctly ( it's printing out 4 until i press a button  then it prints out the right number and when i release the button it writes out 4 again)

```py
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('u'):
        keyboard.press('w')
        keyboard.release('w')
        print(0)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('j'):
        #keyboard.press_and_release('s')
        print(1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('k'):
         #keyboard.press_and_release('d')
         print(2)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
        #keyboard.press_and_release('a')
        print(3)
    else:
        print(4)
        keyboard.release('w')
```

Comment: where does this "keyboard" thing comes from ?

Comment: I think from https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ even if I never used it, anyway I think the question need a bit more details.....

Answer (score 0):

I know that it was a year ago, but I have found this question today. 

Sooo, according to the [Keyboard API](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api): 
`keyboard.press(hotkey)` emulates pressing a hotkey on keyboard. 
`keyboard.release(hotkey)` emulates releasing a hotkey on keyboard. 
A hotkey is an key number, key name, or combination of two or more keys. 

`keyboard.press_and_release(hotkey)` or `keyboard.send(hotkey)` emulates pressing and releasing a key or hotkey. 
Pressing and releasing behaviour depends on values of `do_press` and `do_release` when using `keyboard.send()`.

For example:

```
keyboard.send('space', do_press=True, do_release=True)
```

will emulate pressing **and** releasing *space key*, but:

```
keyboard.send('space', do_press=False, do_release=True)
```

will emulate **only** releasing *space key*. 

`keyboard.is_pressed(key)` returns True if a specified *key* has been pressed, and False otherwise


Hope I've helped!

Comment: Interesting reply.
Does someone know where can I find a list of accepted key codes?
I'm trying to make my script to react when F5 is pressed but it doesn't seem to recognize the 'f5' key.

Answer (score 0):

keyboard.is_pressed() is basically checking if a certain key code is pressed. If you put `keyboard.is_pressed('x')`, it will basically check if the letter x is being pressed, using its keycode, 88.

On the other hand, I can see that the majority of the script works, checking if 'u' is pressed, and then 'elseif's appear fine, but I don't know fully why this part, `keyboard.release('w')`, is at the very bottom. I suggest either removing this line lines:

```
    else: # (this line is fine)
        print(4) # (this line is fine)
        keyboard.release('w')
```

and adjusting the lines a wee bit for this completed code!

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('u'):
        keyboard.press('w')
        keyboard.release('w')
        print(0)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('j'):
        #keyboard.press_and_release('s')
        print(1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('k'):
         #keyboard.press_and_release('d')
         print(2)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
        #keyboard.press_and_release('a')
        print(3)
    else:
        print("No Key pressed.") #alternatively, you can keep it as print(4).
```

Hope this helped, despite being over 4 years late.